# How to save a text value returned from JavaScript to a String Variable in Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, executor

I'm trying to save the text returned by this JavaScript code to a Java String variable, but I cant achieve it. Can anyone please help with this?

My Code:

```
String script = "document.querySelector(\"\"#shift_m_driver>option:nth-child(2)\"\").textContent;";
String DriversDrop = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: illegal character
```

Kindly help me out

Comment: Try to escape the `>` character as well, and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the following string:

```
document.querySelector(""#shift_m_driver>option:nth-child(2)"").textContent;
```

While you should be creating:

```
document.querySelector("#shift_m_driver>option:nth-child(2)").textContent;
```

Try:

```
String script = "document.querySelector(\"#shift_m_driver>option:nth-child(2)\").textContent;";
```

Comment: I would think that because you are converting from String to String, this doesn't matter as he is escaping both `"` anyway. This error is in Java, not in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The error is with Java. Thanks for your help.